# Octicons not working, am I doing something wrong? (html/css/js)

Tags: javascript, html, css, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

So I am fairly new to html and am trying to work with octicons. The process I used is what I saw from a YouTube video so I am not sure if I Made any errors.

I downloaded v 10.1.10 of octicons from GitHub and placed them in my main app folder on vs code. I then opened one of the icons (a briefcase icon) to test, in vs code. I copied the path that showed on the ide when I opened it in VS code and pasted it in the span like below:

```
<div class = "input-group">
                    <span class = "input-group-addon"><span class = "<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill-rule="evenodd" 
                        d="M7.5 1.75C7.5.784 8.284 0 9.25 0h5.5c.966 0 1.75.784 1.75 1.75V4h4.75c.966 0 1.75.784 1.75 1.75v14.5A1.75 1.75 0 0121.25 22H2.75A1.75 1.75 0 011 20.25V5.75C1 4.784 1.784 4 2.75 4H7.5V1.75zm-5 10.24v8.26c0 .138.112.25.25.25h18.5a.25.25 0 00.25-.25v-8.26A4.233 4.233 0 0118.75 13H5.25a4.233 4.233 0 01-2.75-1.01zm19-3.24a2.75 2.75 0 01-2.75 2.75H5.25A2.75 2.75 0 012.5 8.75v-3a.25.25 0 01.25-.25h18.5a.25.25 0 01.25.25v3zm-6.5-7V4H9V1.75a.25.25 0 01.25-.25h5.5a.25.25 0 01.25.25z"/></svg>"></span></span>
                    <input type = "text" class = "form-control" name = "first name" placeholder="First Name">
                </div>
```

When I run this, it doesnt show a briefcase but instead displays a "> next to the first name, in the place of the icon. I am confused as it worked for the guy on YouTube, or maybe im doing something wrong? Could be where I saved the file, or maybe the process has some issue, I really dont know.

I am using Mac OS if this matters.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pasting the svg inside of a `class` attribute (i.e. inside the quotes of a `<span class=""`):

```
<!-- (Your current code) -->
<span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="<svg>...</svg>">"></span>
</span>
```

This causes the HTML to be malformed. Remove the `<span class="` and `">` that are enclosing your svg and it will run fine:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                d="M7.5 1.75C7.5.784 8.284 0 9.25 0h5.5c.966 0 1.75.784 1.75 1.75V4h4.75c.966 0 1.75.784 1.75 1.75v14.5A1.75 1.75 0 0121.25 22H2.75A1.75 1.75 0 011 20.25V5.75C1 4.784 1.784 4 2.75 4H7.5V1.75zm-5 10.24v8.26c0 .138.112.25.25.25h18.5a.25.25 0 00.25-.25v-8.26A4.233 4.233 0 0118.75 13H5.25a4.233 4.233 0 01-2.75-1.01zm19-3.24a2.75 2.75 0 01-2.75 2.75H5.25A2.75 2.75 0 012.5 8.75v-3a.25.25 0 01.25-.25h18.5a.25.25 0 01.25.25v3zm-6.5-7V4H9V1.75a.25.25 0 01.25-.25h5.5a.25.25 0 01.25.25z" />
        </svg>
    </span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first name" placeholder="First Name">
</div>
```

Comment: That really helped I see the icon now thank you so much! Just a quick question, how would I change its color as its black and I want it to be gray? Would it be in the css file?

Comment: @khushi For this, you can use CSS `fill` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

When going to the website and choosing the Icon you'll need to **download the SVG file** put it in your working folder and then link it withing your HTML like this

```html
<img src="./image.svg" alt="alternative text(could be whatever you want)" />
```

Also, you have the wrong code.
Here's how it should look like this

```html
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span>
            <svg xmlns=" http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                    d="M7.5 1.75C7.5.784 8.284 0 9.25 0h5.5c.966 0 1.75.784 1.75 1.75V4h4.75c.966 0 1.75.784 1.75 1.75v14.5A1.75 1.75 0 0121.25 22H2.75A1.75 1.75 0 011 20.25V5.75C1 4.784 1.784 4 2.75 4H7.5V1.75zm-5 10.24v8.26c0 .138.112.25.25.25h18.5a.25.25 0 00.25-.25v-8.26A4.233 4.233 0 0118.75 13H5.25a4.233 4.233 0 01-2.75-1.01zm19-3.24a2.75 2.75 0 01-2.75 2.75H5.25A2.75 2.75 0 012.5 8.75v-3a.25.25 0 01.25-.25h18.5a.25.25 0 01.25.25v3zm-6.5-7V4H9V1.75a.25.25 0 01.25-.25h5.5a.25.25 0 01.25.25z" />
            </svg></span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first name" placeholder="First Name">
</div>
```

Hope this helped :)